# Ubuntu not working for USB

Tags: 13.04, boot, usb, ntfs, unetbootin

I have a USB 64GB (NTFS).

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in the flash drive using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Then I try to boot my USB. It keep showing me some kind of error saying "BOOTMGR is missing. Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to restart."

So I don't know wat's wrong with it. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the error you are getting, please?

Comment: BOOTMGR is missing
Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to restart

Answer (score 0):

That would seem to be a Windows error: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2622803

A Google search brings up pages and pages of this.

You are not booting Ubuntu if you are getting this message.

A possible fix is formatting the USB drive as fat32 or fat before using Unetbootin to create the live USB.

References:

Ubuntu forums discussion on bootmgr error. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1056197

Directions for using Unetbootin. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/

Comment: That's weird.

When I boot up my computer nothing happen.

I only get that error when I boot my USB.

Comment: Sorry, I did a little bit different search and found some info that suggest formatting the USB drive to fat/fat32 before using Unetbootin will solve the error message.

Comment: I can't format to FAT32. I only format to NTFS and exFAT.

Comment: Try formating it to both and see if it works as either one. Did you have a Windows install on this USB before?

Comment: Just tested both of them and still not working. The other one gives different error. Something related to the files or medias.